# Gson custom alternate key/data type deserializer not working?

Tags: kotlin, gson, retrofit2

I have two fields in my json object that could be of two different data types and two different keys I need to be able to convert.

I created a custom deserializer to handle the alternative key and convert to one data type. Using the deserializer results in the entire object being skipped instead of parsed. Why wouldn't something like this work?

```
//model
data class ItemModel(
    val title: String? = ""
    val updateDate: Long? = -1L,
    val formatDuration: String? = "",
)  


//deserializer
class ItemModelDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<ItemModel> {
    override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement, typeOfT: Type, context: JsonDeserializationContext): ItemModel {
        json as JsonObject

        val title = json.get("title").asJsonPrimitive?.asString
        val updateDate = if (json.has("update_date")) json.get("update_date").asJsonPrimitive?.asLong else json.get("modified_at").asJsonPrimitive?.asLong
        val formatDuration = if (json.has("format_duration")) json.get("format_duration").asJsonPrimitive?.asString else json.get("duration").asJsonPrimitive?.asDouble.toString() 

        return ItemModel(title, updateDate, formatDuration)
    }
}

//retrofit
val customGson  = GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(ItemModel::class.java, ItemModelDeserializer()).create()

            return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(BufferedSourceConverterFactory())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(customGson))
                .build()
```

Comment: Could you please double check if it's the same `ItemModel`? You return `VideoItemModel` in the deserializer, but the `ItemModel` provided is a data class, i.e. `VideoItemModel` couldn't inherit it

Comment: I was just trying to abbreviate the code a bit for faster reading. They match in my codebase & I've edited my code here to match. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Just to be sure the issue is really caused by your custom deserializer; could you please omit the `registerTypeAdapter` call (so it is just `val customGson = GsonBuilder().create()`). If that doesn't fail, could you please set a breakpoint or add a logging call in your `ItemModelDeserializer.deserialize` function to see if it is called and how it behaves. Maybe it throws an exception and that is silently ignored somewhere else?